# how to wrap the views inside a HorizontalScrollView?

Tags: android, horizontalscrollview

I have a `HorizontalScrollView` and the numbers 0-9 as `TextView`s as follows.

1. Is it possible to "wrap" the TextViews?

   For example, i want to continuously allow scrolling. Right now, when a user scrolls from 9 to 0, the scrolling stops.

   I want to set the scrolling to continuously (or have the `TextView`s wrap) so that when the user gets to 9 then 0, 1, 2, 3 ... shows up again. And also in the reverse direction; when a user goes to the left past 0, then 9, 8, 7, ... shows up.
2. Is it possible to "center" the currently selected `TextView`?

   If a user clicks 6, and 6 is to the right, can i scroll the `HorizontalScrollView` programmatically such that 6 is now in the center of the screen? I want the same behavior as in the Gallery control.
3. Is it possible to control/override the behavior of the
   `HorizontalScrollView` so that it scrolls only 1 item at a time?

   Right now, if they swipe/fling really fast, the
   `HorizontalScrollView` scrolls all the way to the left (or right,
   depending on the direction of the swipe/fling).

---

```
 <HorizontalScrollView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:id="@+id/hsv">
  <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:orientation="horizontal">
   <TextView android:text="0" android:id="@+id/tv0" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
   <TextView android:text="1" android:id="@+id/tv1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
   <TextView android:text="2" android:id="@+id/tv2" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
   <TextView android:text="3" android:id="@+id/tv3" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
   <TextView android:text="4" android:id="@+id/tv4" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
   <TextView android:text="5" android:id="@+id/tv5" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
   <TextView android:text="6" android:id="@+id/tv6" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
   <TextView android:text="7" android:id="@+id/tv7" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
   <TextView android:text="8" android:id="@+id/tv8" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
   <TextView android:text="9" android:id="@+id/tv9" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
  </LinearLayout>
 </HorizontalScrollView>
```

any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There's already a couple of excellent answers provided on SO

- [How to scroll "infinitely" wide view in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1582326/how-to-scroll-infinitely-wide-view-in-android)

*Accepted answer from above*

> if you are working with list/grid or anything that uses Adapter for
>   data, you can use a most excellent class written by CommonsWare and
>   available here:
>
> http://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-endless
>
> it was was specifically for this purpose

Comment: While helpful, both links you provided lead the OP to other resources. Would you mind adding some context around the second link?

Comment: @Tim Post - the 2nd link is the C+P of the accepted answer of the SO link.